# Netbeans 8.0 Code Folding Methods Only

Tags: php, netbeans, code-formatting, code-folding

In Netbeans 7.3.1, there was an option to collapse by default "methods".  It seems that in 8.0, this option has been replaced by an option to collapse by default "code blocks."  The difference between the two was that "methods" folded only methods and functions, whereas "code blocks" folds, in addition to methods and functions, the content of loops, if statements, and any other chunk of code that Netbeans can determine is discrete.

I'd like it to go back to folding only my higher level methods.  Is there an option that I am missing that would do that, or are we stuck with this "upgrade?"

I'm using just the PHP/HTML Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After watching this video, I discovered that the "Functions and Methods" folding option had been moved under drop menu for a specific language.  By grabbing the PHP dropdown in Options>Editor>Folding, I was able to get back my function/method only folding option.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-KIX7iAlro